# Помогите определить тип сказуемого

Tags: синтаксис, тип-сказуемого

> Литература — яркий пример единства наук о человеке.

В этом предложении сказуемое простое или составное именное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Встречалось мне предложение "Лингвистика — яркий пример единства наук о человеке", но литература-то наукой не является.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, составное именное. Простое сказуемое может быть выражено только глаголом, а его вообще в предложении нет.

Подробнее: http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/195-skazuemoeiosnovnyetipy.html.

Answer (score 1):

> В этом предложении сказуемое простое или составное именное?

Если я правильно понял вопрос, речь идёт о том, как следует характеризовать сказуемое, выраженное только именной частью (без нулевой формы связки). Что это: **простое именное сказуемое** или же **составное именное сказуемое**?

Вопрос такой может иметь место. Понятие простого именного сказуемого в науке о русском языке существует. В "Словаре-справочнике лингвистических терминов" Д.Э. Розенталя и М.А. Теленковой (М., 1976) говорится:

> [**именное сказуемое простое**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/481/%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) –
>   по встречающейся в некоторых работах (в том числе академической
>   “Грамматике русского языка”, 1960) терминологии сказуемое, состоящее
>   только из именной части, без связки. *Моя сестра **учительница**.
>   Книга **интересная**. Липы **в цвету***.

Такой термин используется и в некоторых современных пособиях по русскому языку. См., к примеру, здесь   [[**Л.Я. Лачимова, Т.И. Гусева, Е.В. Бегаева, А.А. Янсюкевич. Современный русский язык. Практическое пособие. М., 2005**]](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/716-skazuemoe-vyirajennoe-narechiem-67761.html):

> «Она теперь ай-ай-ай» (Леск.) (здесь простое именное сказуемое).

Но такие пособия немногочисленны. Большая часть лингвистов считает, что формы именного сказуемого без связки тесно примыкают к формам именного сказуемого со связкой и нет достаточных оснований отрывать их друг от друга.

Такая точка зрения принята и в официальных альтернативных учебных комплексах для школ, рекомендованных Минобразования. Для обеих форм сказуемого в них используется единый термин – **СОСТАВНОЕ ИМЕННОЕ СКАЗУЕМОЕ**.

Comment: А что такое «официальные альтернативные учебные комплексы для школ, рекомендованные Минобразования»?..

Comment: Так эти комплексы характеризует Литневская. См. http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part01